# What is the minimum graphics memory (VRAM) for Unity Desktop? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, unity, graphics

> *(**Info**: I searched this on Google several times and I could not find anything, so if this is a duplicate, let me know. Also, let me
>   know if I'm unclear or too broad.)*

I am getting a new motherboard on Saturday and my friend (who is building it) said that he is also bringing a graphics card (an AGP one with 512 MB video memory).

When he mentioned it, I was happy to know that now I can "break free" from the lightweight Ubuntu options (Xubuntu, Lubuntu) and use Unity desktop once again.

But, I had some doubts. Will 512 MB be enough for Unity on 16.04? I think that 64 ~ 70 MB is the bare minimum (tested with 96 MB on a 14.04 VM & with 128 MB on a 16.04 VM). Also, will AGP be fast enough to render the graphics? There is a lot of debate going online on whether they are faster than PCI or not.

I'm open to any suggestions.

***EDIT***: This is the graphics card I'm getting:

Radeon X1650Pri Dual Link DVI 512MB DDR2 (128-bit)

Is it OK?

Comment: I truly think you'll have no problem whatsoever with Unity... But let's say you were to encounter a few issues... The next best bet I would recommend is using something such as `xfce4`

Comment: I doubt Unity is a good idea for an AGP card, most of which are quite old. Do you know which model you are going to get? Also, here is a [HW requirements page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/UnityHardwareRequirements).

Comment: @NerdOfCode I don't want a great graphics card (2 GB+) for gaming etc. I only use my Ubuntu PC for basic stuff (old OS emulation, Internet browsing, listening to music etc.). My current Dell OptiPlex GX270 with 1 GB RAM and 8MB integrated graphics can sure handle those. I just want the basic use of Unity as it is (launching apps, dock, dash etc.)

Comment: @mikewhatever I don't want a great graphics card (2 GB+) for gaming etc. I only use my Ubuntu PC for basic stuff (old OS emulation, Internet browsing, listening to music etc.). My current Dell OptiPlex GX270 with 1 GB RAM and 8MB integrated graphics can sure handle those. I just want the basic use of Unity as it is (launching apps, dock, dash etc.) Also, I don't know what model I'm getting. I just know that it is 512 MB. This is the biggest (in MB) graphics card he has available. The others are 64 MB.

Comment: @mikewhatever OK, I checked the hardware requirements page. The minimum is 384 MB. So I guess that 512 MB is OK.

Comment: @mikewhatever Sorry for bugging you... But this is kind of interesting. I got the model of the graphics card. Check the edit.