# How to copy my /home folder data to a new partition and mount it as /home?

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, home-directory

As you can see in my previous post (click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014656/what-is-the-minimum-graphics-memory-vram-for-unity-desktop-ubuntu-16-04)), I'm getting a new motherboard. However, I saw in WikiHow (click [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-a-Motherboard)) that I have to reinstall ***every*** operating system in my drives. However, (also because I am a distro hopper sometimes) I'm fed of backing up my entire `/home` folder and copying it to the new installation.

I have seen somewhere that if you don't want to wipe the entire Linux partition and lose data, you can create a partition during installation & mount it in the `/home` mount point. I have seen it multiple times, and now (since I want to change from Xubuntu to Ubuntu) I regret not doing that.

I can copy my files on to an external hard drive, but my problem is creating the partition & the mount point. Will it be recognized by the system and `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: There is an entire article about that on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving.

Comment: There is probably no reason for re-installing the OS because of a change of motherboard. This should not be a problem for ubuntu. and about migration from xubuntu to ubuntu, you could simply remove the xubuntu-desktop package and add the ubuntu-desktop package, see also : https://askubuntu.com/a/19944/454520

Comment: @pim Ubuntu isn't my issue, it's Windows!(drivers & dualboot) Plus, I want to remove the pre-installed Xubuntu packages and have a fresh Ubuntu install.